# Can't compile because replace function improperly used?

Tags: c++, string, csv

I stream in a text file, which uses semi colons to separate values.
I want to replace the semi colon with a colon, and stream out into a newly made .csv file

CURRENTLY, the program runs without an error during compiling, but when i specify an output filename,
it creates the .csv file then crashes.

I can not upload images in my post because I am a new member...

Here is the Visual Studio Output When I compile:

```
BEGIN
1>------ Build started: Project: export, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  export.cpp
1>  Generating code
1>  Finished generating code
1>  export.vcxproj -> J:\Bar\OIL Final\export\Release\export.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
END
```

Here is the 'guts' of the code:

```
string file_type = ".csv";                          //  Stores the Export
```

Filename Extension
    string file_path = "";                              //  Stores the

Export Filename and Path
    string filename;

```
bool validateExportFilename()
{
    bool valid_filename = false;                        // Holds the Bool Value which
```

maintains a loop until vaid file is found

```
    while (valid_filename == false)
    {
        std::cout << "\t\tPlease Enter A Name For These Results:\t";
        cin >> filename;

        file_path = export_folder + filename + file_type;

        ifstream check_filename;                        // Define the Input
```

File Stream --> using USER entered file name
            check_filename.open(file_path);                 // Open the file fresh - all

positions in memory (i.e. getline() location) will be reset.

```
        if (check_filename.fail())
        {
            t("FILE NAME IS VALID..."); //  TRACE MESSAGE
            valid_filename = true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\n\t\t\t[!] ERROR - File Exists. Try again. [!]\n" << endl;   //
```

Notify USER of Error
                std::cout << "\n\n\t\t\t";

```
                // Format the pause command's screen output
            system("pause");                                    

                    // Pause to give user the time to find the file
        }
        check_filename.close();
    }
    return 0;
}   

if (inFile.is_open())
{
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        string line = "";
        getline(inFile, line);
        line.replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ";", ", ");
        outFile << line << endl;
    }
}

t("End Function - Replace");    //  TRACE MESSAGE

inFile.close();
outFile.close();

return 0;
```

Here is a sample of the data of the text file, i am trying to stream in, and turn into a CSV file:

```
4/09/2013;10:34:57 AM;4780;1129;63;32;19.9;17.7;13.5;12.6;OK;0;50;4.77;26; 144 
4/09/2013;10:35:11 AM;4546;1117;69;30;19.8;17.7;13.7;12.5;OK;0;50;4.76;26; 143
```

And here is what i want to stream out to a different file, but with the extention .CSV instead of .TXT:

```
4/09/2013,10:34:57 AM,4780,1129,63,32,19.9,17.7,13.5,12.6,OK,0,50,4.77,26, 144 
4/09/2013,10:35:11 AM,4546,1117,69,30,19.8,17.7,13.7,12.5,OK,0,50,4.76,26, 143
```

And here is what the debugger outputs when the program crashes:

```
The thread 0x1d5c has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[10012] export.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

Unhandled exception at 0x637B7666 (msvcr120.dll) in export.exe: Fatal program exit requested.
```

Call stack lists this:

```
msvcr120.dll!637b7666() Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for msvcr120.dll]  
[External Code] 
>   export.exe!replaceAndExport() Line 204  C++
    export.exe!wmain() Line 79  C++
```

And under Autos:

```
-       inFile  {_Filebuffer={_Set_eback=0x00000000 <NULL> _Set_egptr=0x00000000 <NULL>
```

_Pcvt=0x00000000  ...} }  std::basic_ifstream >
    +       std::basic_istream >    {_Chcount=0 }

std::basic_istream >
    +       std::basic_ios >    {_Mystrbuf=0x001efb88 {_Set_eback=0x00000000

_Set_egptr=0x00000000  _Pcvt=0x00000000  ...} ...}

std::basic_ios >
    +       _Filebuffer {_Set_eback=0x00000000  _Set_egptr=0x00000000  _Pcvt=0x00000000

...} std::basic_filebuf >
    -       line    ""  std::basic_string,std::allocator >
            [size]  0   unsigned int
            [capacity]  15  unsigned int
    +       [Raw View]  0x001efcd8 {...}

std::basic_string,std::allocator > *
    -       outFile {_Filebuffer={_Set_eback=0x00000000  _Set_egptr=0x00000000

_Pcvt=0x00000000  ...} }  std::basic_ofstream >
    +       std::basic_ostream >    {...}

std::basic_ostream >
    +       std::basic_ios >    {_Mystrbuf=0x001efc34 {_Set_eback=0x00000000

_Set_egptr=0x00000000  _Pcvt=0x00000000  ...} ...}

std::basic_ios >
    +       _Filebuffer {_Set_eback=0x00000000  _Set_egptr=0x00000000  _Pcvt=0x00000000

...} std::basic_filebuf >

I can see the .CSV file being created, but the file remains empty at 0KB and a split second after the file is

created, the application crashes.

I feel like i may need to adjust the "read a line, swap commas in" process so i dont overflow the buffer, but

i am not a programmer so i dont really know...

Comment: This question has formatting & content problems, Please be specific . Don't just copy paste the code & debug log here.

Comment: If you click on the line in the call stack it will show you in the code exactly where the crash is.  We can't tell because we don't know which line is line 204.  I'm not even sure you've posted anything from the replaceAndExport function since you've shown such tiny pieces in such a convoluted way.

Comment: @user1, please feel free to check again, I have corrected the formatting in my last edit.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thankyou, ill see what i get :)

Comment: Reduce your code to a short complete example with the input it is crashing with and edit that into the question.  I have no idea what all the asterisks are about from your last edit.  It's enough to just format code using the button in the editor.

Comment: @Nard, i am not a programmer, please forgive the lack of transparency of my function naming.

check_filename is my function to check if the file with that filename exists.

In the case of creating a new file, I need to make sure the name doesn't exist already.

Hence the entered filename is VALID, if it doesn't already exist,

else it notifies the user that the file exists and they must enter a different filename.

Comment: @RetiredNinja i was trying to make the code more visible and separate from the text of my question, i did not realise this editor would remove all tabulation formatting.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time so far in trying to understand my problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, currently the first issue is the crash. Im sorry that this post is not as transparent as we would all like it to be :(

Comment: @MatthewKessanis You're right in that there's a problem with `line.replace`. You're using it wrong. [string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) takes in a range within the `string` and everything within that range is replaced with the string you pass in as the last parameter. You should try using [std::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/) instead. You can perform a simple test first by commenting that one line out and see if it still crashes. Though regardless of whether it crashes or not, that line is still wrong.

Comment: @Nard, Yes, Commenting out the line 203: line.replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ";", ", "); has resolved the crash. The data exports, just without commas replacing the semi-colons.

Sorry to be a pain, but what must I change in the REPLACE function to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @Nard, or must i change the data type of the variable LINE to something else instead of a string, for example char[128]?

Answer (score 1):

As you've pointed out, the problem lies with the line `line.replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ";", ", ");`

Since you seem determined to emphasize on the fact that you're not a programmer, I will not go into detail as to why it compiles even though you're using it wrong. Instead, I will explain how this function is supposed to be used. While they are a number of variations to this function, the main purpose of `string::replace` is to replace a portion of one `string` with another `string`.

Simply put, I can use `string::replace` to change `Hello World` to `Goodbye Cruel World` by stating that I want `Hello` to be **replaced** with `Goodbye Cruel`. This, of course, works for not just the beginning but also any part of the string.

So that's not the function you want.

The function you want to use is present in `<algorithm>` called `replace`. `replace` is similar to `string::replace` except that instead of replacing a range, you specify the old value (in this case `';'`) and the new value (in this case ':') and you pass them into the function like this, `replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ';', ':');`. Now what `replace` will do is search through the range from `line.begin()` to `line.end()` for all instances of `';'` and replace them with `':'`.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Greatly appreciated, thank you.

I should add, the reason replace wasn't working as std::replace until this moment is because i actually had 1 character in the FIND argument, and 2 characters in the REPLACE argument, because CSV files seem to need a COMMA and a SPACE to separate values.

Comment: Actually in using std:replace i now have a compiler error, but thank you for all your help Nard :) I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: funnily enough, Changing the 66 and 99 " quotation marks to single apostrophes ' resolved this bug.

Comment: @MatthewKessanis That's simply because double quotation marks represent `string`s (more specifically string literals) while single quotation marks represent `char`s.   `line` is a `string` and `string`s are made up of `char`s. If you use replace with `line`, you'll be comparing the third parameter with `char`s, and you cannot compare `string`s with `char`s. Therefore, it results in a compiler error.